# PHPVideoToolkit getFFmpegInfo() returns an array with empty codecs

Tags: ffmpeg, centos

I have install ffmpeg and `ffmpeg -codecs` returns a huge list of codecs. But output of the following code:

```
    $ffmpeg = $toolkit->getFFmpegInfo(FALSE);
    print_r($ffmpeg);
```

is this:

```
  ...
  [codecs] => Array
        (
            [video] => Array
                (
                )

            [audio] => Array
                (
                )

            [subtitle] => Array
                (
                )

        )
```

It doesn't find any codec. Any suggestion? (I have installed ffmpeg from source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have not configured (or you have misconfigured) the **PHPVIDEOTOOLKIT_FFMPEG_BINARY** constant; it should be set to the full path of the `ffmpeg` command. For example:

```
define('PHPVIDEOTOOLKIT_FFMPEG_BINARY', '/usr/bin/ffmpeg');
```

To determine the correct path, execute the command `which ffmpeg`.
If you're using PHP5, you can find a usage example of the `getFFmpegInfo()` function in the [examples/php5/example09.php](http://code.google.com/p/phpvideotoolkit/source/browse/trunk/phpvideotoolkit/examples/php5/example09.php) script.
Before running the examples scripts, you have to edit the configuration file [examples/example-config.php](http://code.google.com/p/phpvideotoolkit/source/browse/trunk/phpvideotoolkit/examples/example-config.php) and adjust the various `define` with the correct paths for your system.
Have a look at the [DEMOS](http://code.google.com/p/phpvideotoolkit/source/browse/trunk/phpvideotoolkit/DEMOS) file for a description of what each example does.

Answer (score 0):

I found the version of FFMPEG I was using was outputting the codecs in a different format, in the getFFmpegInfo method I had to modify the below regular expression:

Original:

```
/ ((?:[DEVAST ]{6})|(?:[DEVASTFB ]{8})|(?:[DEVASIL\.]{6})) ([A-Za-z0-9\_]+) (.+)/
```

For my server:

```
/([DEVASI\.]{4}) ([A-Za-z0-9\_]+) (.+)/
```